# Splash screen with transparency png. - C++ Builder

Tags: screen, loading, transparent

I want to create a splash screen before my application starts, but I'm having some troubles with it. I have a image which contains some drawings and it is transparent (has no background).
Something like "Blade and Soul" splash screen. I can't post a link here with it, sorry.
I tried to create a panel, give it a color and in my form, I set that color to be shown as transparent, but I can still see the borders even though I have set it to be border less.

And another problem that I have encountered is about 3 forms. I have the first form (main form), a second form and a third form. I want them to be shown as follow: Main form (stays 5 seconds on desktop, gets away- I want to hide it - then comes the 2nd form) Second form (stays on desktop until I press a button which shows the 3rd form and makes the second one disappears).
I did this by writing the following code:

```
Form2->Show();
this->Hide();
```

Of course, I added a timer and this code is executed after the timer finishes counting, so it's 5 seconds.
It works flawless, but from Form2 to Form3 it doesn't work correctly.

```
Form3->Show();
this->Hide();
```

I created a button and I wrote this code in it. Form3 appears while Form2 dissapears but then Form2 appears back and I don't understand why...

Sorry for my bad english. :)

Comment: you are asking too many things at once ... focus on single one and when working move to another... I would start with the Splash... We need to see the image so post it somwhere. Typical problem is wrong encoding somwhere along the way like JPG which is lossy corrupting the Transparent color making either artifacts or disabling the transparency fully. make sure you set the `TransparentColor = True` and `TransparentColorValue` with the color you want ... beware some colors are `RRGGBB` and some `BBGGRR` so may be you just used wrong order? without sample and code we can only guess...

Comment: I would force encoding by setting the `bmp->BitmapMode=bmDIB` and `bmp->PixelFormat=pf32bit` just to be sure encoding is the same no matter what... Also I do hiding showing of forms by setting `Visible` property instead